# How to solve matrix equation $\mathbf{AX} = \mathbf{B}$ for $\mathbf{A}$ based on initial guess?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

The problem has the general form of

$\mathbf{AX} = \mathbf{B}$

I am trying to estimate the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ ($m\times n$ where $m<n$) which describes the behavior of a physical system. I have some input stored as the columns of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ ($n\times k$) and the output stored in the columns of the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ ($m\times k$).
I already have a good initial guess for $\mathbf{A}$, but it can definitely be improved.
I have been trying to use an objective function: minimize: $||\mathbf{AX} - \mathbf{B}||^2 + \gamma ||\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{\hat{A}}||^2$, where $\gamma$ is a regularization parameter ($\gamma > 0$), and  $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$ is my initial guess.

However, I am not that familiar with linear algebra, and I therefore have some difficulties with solving the problem or indeed finding information on *how* to solve it. Initially I would think that I would have to differentiate the objective function with respect to $\mathbf{A}$, setting that equal to $0$, and then solving for $\mathbf{A}$, but even that causes problems due to my lacking knowledge of differentiation rules with matrices.

Hope you can help me

### Update: Let me be more concrete

The entire setup is a hyperspectral thermal camera: A thermal camera where a scanning Fabry-Pérot interferometer (SFPI) has been placed in front of the lens. The distance between the mirrors of the SFPI determines the distribution of wavelengths entering the camera. $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix describing the transmission of the SFPI, where each row represent a given mirror separation and the columns represent the wavenumber of the incident light. This is why I have a good initial estimate for $\mathbf{A}$ given by the Airy function.

$$T = \frac{1}{1 + F\sin^2{2\pi d k}}$$
where $d$ is the mirror separation and $k$ is the wavenumber of the incident light. $F$ is the Coefficient of Finesse described by the mirror reflectance, $r$:
$$F = \frac{4r^2}{(1-r^2)^2}$$
Using a reflectance of $r=0.8$ this gives rise to an initial guess matrix $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$ as given in the figure below (both with physical units and with the pure row/col indices):

[image: Initial guess for matrix A based on the Airy function]

Each column of $\mathbf{X}$ is a transmission FTIR measurement of a sample (multiplied with a 150 °C black body distribution to correspond with experimental setup). The columns of $\mathbf{B}$ are then the corresponding interferograms recorded by the hyperspectral camera.
[image: Matrix X and matrix B]

##### Solving directly

When I try to solve the problem directly using the equation supplied by @greg:

$$\mathbf{A} = (\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}^T + \gamma_{init}\mathbf{\hat{A}})(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T + \gamma_{reg} \mathbf{M})^{-1}$$

I am able to get a promising result if I use a 2$^\textrm{nd}$ order regularisation to suppress oscillations in the result by setting

$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \dots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
\dots & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
\dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Even if I use a random matrix as an initial guess, I am able to get a solution, which resembles the Airy matrix (using $\gamma_{init} = 10^{-7}$ and $\gamma_{reg} = 10^{-3}$). Here I get a reconstruction error og $||\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{B}||=84314$. The following figure represents the solution (displayed in gray scale) found using this method with the Airy matrix overlayed on top.

[image: Estimated system matrix]

Even though the initial guess is random, it still appears to find a solution which resembles the airy function. This to me indicates that we're onto something. Notice how the maximum of the fit is slightly shifted compared to the Airy function - this is the kind of 'improvements' which give me more insight in the actual behaviour of the system. However, there are some flaws... most notably that some of the entries in the matrix are negative, which I would like to suppress.

##### Solving iteratively

I then tried to implement the iterative solution also proposed by @greg using the Barzilai-Borwein stepper based on his pseudo code. This does indeed promote non-negative solutions, but the sultions I am able to find does not really change the shape of the initial Airy function. Depending on the weights ($\gamma_{init}$ and $\gamma_{reg}$) I get solutions which are somewhere in between the Airy function (with added noise) or a similar solution to what I get from solving the problem directly if I set $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{I}$.  This is illustrated in the figure below where once again, the grayscale image represent the solution for $\mathbf{A}$ and the yellow overlay is the maximum of the Airy function which has here been used as the initial guess.

[image: Different solutions of A found using iterative method]

When setting $\gamma_{init} = 10^{1}$ and $\gamma_{reg} = 10^{3}$ I get the following evolution of $||\mathbf{G}||$ and the reconstruction error $||\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{B}||$:

[image: Evolution of reconstruction error]

So while $||\mathbf{G}||$ is decreasing as expected, the reconstruction error only changes slightly... And for the worse. Does this indicate a wrong implementation of the solver from my part? I should add that for other configurations of $\gamma_{init}$ and $\gamma_{reg}$, the reconstruction error does decrease, but the change is still not that substantial. For example going from $||\mathbf{AX}-\mathbf{B}|| = 2.52932\times 10^5$ to $2.52927\times 10^5$ after 250 iterations where it appears to flatten out.

**I guess my general question is**: If my implementaiton of the iterative solver is correct, is there a way to guide it more towards the solution found when solved directly with the 2$^\textrm{nd}$ order regularisation?

Comment: Have you tried solving the augmented system $[X^T|B^T]$ using standard methods? If you do this an transpose the resulting matrix you should get your solution for $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I'm afraid I would need you to clarify what you mean by *solving* the augmented system. The augmented part I understand, but solve it with respect to what?

Comment: Typically, if you're interested in solving the linear system $Ax=b$ for $x,$ you first construct the augmented matrix $[A|b]$, use row operations to calculate $\text{rref}[A|b],$ identify free/basic variables, and then solve it for $x$. In your problem the augmented part is the entire matrix $B^T$ but the process will be the same, and you can solve $[X^T|B^T]$ for $A^T$.

Comment: Do you have one $X$ and  $B$ or multiple ones?

Comment: @Matthew H - Arh thank you, I see - I'll give it a go

Comment: @John Alexiou I only have one. The columns of $\mathbf{X}$ each describe a spectrum, which is measured by the system represented by $\mathbf{A}$. Then $\mathbf{B}$ is the measurements which are the output of the system itself. Both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are real data and I would therefore like to find the $\mathbf{A}$ which best describes the relationship between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
\def\L{\left} \def\R{\right}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\L(#1\R)}}
\def\g{\gamma} \def\l{\lambda} \def\A{\widehat A}
\def\e{\exp_\bullet} \def\f{\log_\bullet}
$Calculate the gradient of the objective function as follows
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac12\L(AX-B\R):\L(AX-B\R) + \tfrac{\g}2\L(A-\A\R):\L(A-\A\R) \\
d\phi
 &=\L(AX-B\R):\L(dA\:X\R) + \g\L(A-\A\R):dA \\
 &=\L(AXX^T-BX^T + \g A-\g\A\R):dA \\
\\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A}
 &= A\L(XX^T+\g I\R) - \L(BX^T+\g\A\R)
 \;\doteq\; G \\
}$$
You can set $G=0$ and solve for $A$ directly (via matrix inversion)
$$A = \L(BX^T+\g\A\R) \L(XX^T+\g I\R)^{-1}$$
or use $G$ in an iterative (gradient descent) algorithm
$$\eqalign{
&Z = XX^T+\g I \\
&Y = BX^T+\g\A \\
&A_{\tt1} = \A \\
&{\rm for\;} k = {\tt1}\;{\rm to}\;k_{max} \\
&\qquad G_k = A_k Z - Y \\
&\qquad A_{k+1} = A_{k} - \l_k G_k \\
&\qquad k = k + {\tt1} \\
}$$
and stop when $\|G_k\|$ is small enough for your intended application.  The stepsize $\l_k$ is specified by the descent algorithm ([Barzilai-Borwein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barzilai-Borwein_method) is my personal favorite).

---

In the above, a colon denotes the Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:G &= \operatorname{Tr}\L(A^TG\R) \;&=\; G:A \\
\L(AZ\R):G &= A:\L(GZ^T\R) \;&=\; Z:\L(A^TG\R) \\
}$$

### Update

If you need a non-negative solution $\L(A_{ij}\ge0\R)$ introduce a new independent *unconstrained* matrix $U$ and use it to construct the $A$ matrix via an **element-wise** exponential function, i.e.
$$A = \e(U) \quad\implies\quad dA = A\odot dU$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

The gradient wrt $U$ is a straightforward calculation
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &=\L(AXX^T-BX^T + \g A-\g\A\R):\c{dA} \\
 &=\L(AXX^T-BX^T + \g A-\g\A\R):\CLR{A\odot dU} \\
 &=A\odot\L(AXX^T-BX^T + \g A-\g\A\R):dU \\
\\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial U}
 &= A\odot\L(A\L(XX^T+\g I\R) - \L(BX^T+\g\A\R)\R) \\
 &= A\odot G\;\doteq\; F \\
}$$
While there is no direct solution for this problem, you **can** still use the gradient descent algorithm to calculate the optimal $U$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
\def\U{\widehat U}
&Z = XX^T+\g I \\
&Y = BX^T+\g\A \\
&U_{\tt1} = \f\L(\A\R) \\
&{\rm for\;} k = {\tt1}\;{\rm to}\;k_{max} \\
&\qquad A_k = \e(U_k) \\
&\qquad F_k = A_k\odot\L(A_k Z - Y\R) \\
&\qquad U_{k+1} = U_{k} - \l_k F_k \\
&\qquad k = k + {\tt1} \\
}$$
After which you can recover the corresponding non-negative solution $\:A=\e(U)$

### Update 2

Let me elaborate on adapting the Barzilai-Borwein method to matrix variables with a bit of pseudo-code.

Include $\,G=0\,$ in the initializations, then
$$\eqalign{
\def\DG{\Delta G}
\def\DU{\Delta U}
\def\DU{\Delta U}
{\rm for}&\;k=1\to 9999 \\
&\quad A = \e(U) \\
&\quad \DG = A\odot\L(A*Z-Y\R) - G \\
&\quad G = G + \DG \\
\\
&\quad {\rm if}\;\|G\| \le10^{-13}{\;\rm then\; STOP} \\
\\
&\quad \l = 10^{-6} \\
\\
&\quad {\rm if}\;k>1{\;\rm then} \\
&\quad\quad \l = \frac{\DU:\DU}{\DU:\DG}
 \quad{\sf OR}\quad \l = \frac{\DU:\DG}{\DG:\DG} \\
&\quad {\rm endif} \\
\\
&\quad {\rm if}\;\l<0{\;\rm then} \\
&\quad\quad \l = \L[\frac{\DU:\DU}{\DG:\DG}\R]^{\frac12} \\
&\quad {\rm endif} \\
\\
&\quad \DU = -\l G \\
&\quad U = U + \DU \\
{\rm end} \\
}$$
Note that three different BB step lengths are shown above.

The first is called the *long step*, the second is the *short step*, and the third is the *positive step* which is the geometric mean of the first two.

The *long step* often converges a bit more quickly, but I usually use the *short step*.  The problem is that the cross product $\L(\DG:\DU\R)$ term can be negative or zero, so I'd rather have it in the numerator than the denominator. If the term is negative, then switch to the *positive step* so that you keep going downhill.

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg. When would I use an iterative scheme instead of calculating $\mathbf{A}$ directly? Is it if $\mathbf{XX}^T$ is ill conditioned?

Comment: If $\widehat A$ is a good initial guess, then it might take only one or two iterations to find the solution, and that will be cheaper than inverting $Z$, especially when $n$ very large.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work like a charm. 
Just to complicate things further... Do you know if it is possible to apply some sort of non-negativity constraint to the solution?

Comment: Thanks a ton @greg . I would have never been able to find that on my own. I will give it a shot an see if I can make it work. Do you have any suggestions for literature on this subject? I struggle to find relevant references on these kind of problems.

Comment: For non-negativity constraints, I recommend [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc/10.1.1.157.9203) as a starting point.

Comment: Maybe a question with an obvious answer: How do I modify the Barzilai-Borwein Method to work with matrices? I have a hard time figuring out how I go from:
$\lambda_k = \frac{\mathbf{s}^T_{k-1}\mathbf{s}_{k-1}}{\mathbf{s}^T_{k-1}\mathbf{y}_{k-1}}$
where
$\mathbf{s}_{k-1} = \mathbf{x}_k - \mathbf{x}_{k-1}$ and $\mathbf{y}_{k-1} = \mathbf{g}_k - \mathbf{g}_{k-1}$ with $\mathbf{g}_{k} = \mathbf{Ax_k} - \mathbf{b}$
and convert it to a matrix format. 
Maybe you can help @greg?

Comment: I added some pseudo-code to the post. The main idea is to replace the vector inner product with the matrix inner product (aka the Frobenius product)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @greg - it is immensely appreciated. I have updated my original question with a more concrete explanation of the problem I am facing as well as what results I have got this far. I am still struggling with the iterative solution, and I am not sure if it is my implementation which is wrong or inappropriate choice of variables. Since I am expecting a solution which is similar to the airy function, should I do something to encurage sparsity?

Comment: $
\def\g{{\large\gamma}} \def\gi{\g_{init}} \def\gr{\g_{reg}}
\def\A{{\widehat A}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)} \def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
$The BB algorithm is straightforward, so I'm confident that your implementation is okay.
And your $\|G\|$ plot is typical for its performance on large nonlinear problems.
You can implement your 2nd order regularization by setting
$$ Z = XX^T + \gr M $$ prior to the for-loop

Comment: But from your plots, it appears that you're using Matlab.
So instead of rolling your own solver, vectorize the regularized matrix equation
$$\eqalign{
\def\g{{\large\gamma}} \def\gi{\g_{init}} \def\gr{\g_{reg}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\A{{\widehat A}}
&A\LR{XX^T+\gr M} = \LR{BX^T+\gi\A} \\
&AZ = Y \\
&(Z^T\otimes I)\vc A = \vc Y \\
&Qa = y \\
}$$
and use Matlab's built-in non-negative solver
`a = lsqnonneg(Q,y)` followed by `A = reshape(a,m,n)`
to recover the matrix form.

Comment: Thanks again @greg - this is a huge help. Actually, I am using python, but I imagine that I can use the non-negative least squares implementation in SciPy in a similar fashion. Just to make sure, $\mathbf{Q}$ is generated by taking the Kronecker product of $\mathbf{Z}$ and an equally sized identity matrix? My problem is that $\mathbf{Z}$ has a size of $2801 \times 2801$, which would make $\mathbf{Q}$ an $6\cdot 10^{13}$ element matrix. Do you have a suggestion to get around this? Am I better off using the sparse matrix implementation in Matlab since we are working with the identity matrix?

Comment: ... Or sorry... $\mathbf{I}$ should have probably be square with the same number of rows as $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, the dimensions of $I$ equal the first dimension of $A$.  Also, I haven't mentioned it before, but in the iterative method the Frobenius product should be implemented as a double sum not as a trace, i.e. $$A:B = \sum_j\sum_kA_{jk}B_{jk}\;$$ which you can implement as a Hadamard product followed by a summation over all of the components, e.g. in Julia it's written as `sum(A.*B)` Finally, any sparse matrix implementation should be able to handle matrices of the given dimensions.

Comment: Hi @greg. I have tried implementing the nonnegative least square solver in Matlab, but with no luck. It appears that the `lsqnonneg` function itself does not handle sparse matrices. When I supply $\mathbf{Q}$ as a sparse matrix it fits in memory just fine, but during the calculation Matlab tries to allocate 70 times the memory for a matrix (not sparse) of the same size. Do you know if it is possible to either chop the problem up into smaller chunks, or do you happen to know a sparse implementation of the nonnegative least squares solver - not necessarily Matlab or python?

Comment: I have [some Julia code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tJkVDGaHfnW_CQEZvxm2eMmJ5xF1yRrg) that solves
$$
\def\frob#1{\big\|#1\big\|^2_F}
\frob{LXK^T-M} \;+\; \lambda\frob{X}
$$
Replacing $X$ with $(A-\widehat A)$ will convert your problem into the same form.

Comment: That is to say, it solves the **non-negative** version of the problem. I also put a copy of the relevant PDF articles into the shared folder.

Comment: Your help is truly appreciated, @greg. I will take a closer look at it in the near future